# can I safely delete thunderbird from 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: thunderbird

I don't use Thunderbird and never will.  All of my email clients are web-based.  So I would like to uninstall the Thunderbird client from my laptop, but don't want to break Ubuntu.  Is it safe to do this?  If not I can live with the bloatware.

F

Comment: Leaving it there costs you nothing.

Comment: @heynnema -- technically a cost is incurred in additional time and network usage when installing updates.  But this is a nit.

Comment: It would be better to use TB with POP3/IMAP, and get away from your web-based mail apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you don't use it you can safely delete it. The only negative side-effect is that you will not have any application in the system to handle "mailto:" URLs, if you ever happen to click on one. A working mail client is required to handle these URLs. (But many people live without it, using only web-based mail as you are ;)).